# why does this bootstrap container not appear in the center even when margin is equal on both ends?

Tags: html, google-chrome, bootstrap-4

I added a bootstrap container to my webpage. You can see that the margin left and right has been set to auto as bootstrap containers by default are. But the container is not centered horizontally. The left margin is visibly bigger than the right margin (see the orange portion on either side of the container). 150px as margin on either side(according to chrome dev tools, see box model on the right) should center the div...but it doesn't. Is this a problem with how my browser is showing this window or is there something actually wrong with my code?

[image: this is a screenshot of how the chrome developer tools looks like when I select the container in question]

Comment: I would like to clarify here that I am using quite an outdated version of chromium here because a raspberry pi is all I have right now and the chromium on it is practically stuck to v78.0.3904.10.. Is this a problem with this chromium version?

Comment: can you confirm if there is no horizontal scroll?

Comment: oh yes I see there is a horizontal scroll... How do I prevent this? I want the whole container to be always centered and have no need to scroll horizontally... should setting overflowX to hidden fix this issue?

Comment: instead of `container` class use `container-fluid` class and you can set max-width if required.

Comment: Yeah I tried it but still..no matter what I do there is some scroll space remaining...how do I eliminate it? Shouldn't setting max-width to 100vw eliminate the need of a horizontal scroll... I don't want a horizontal scroll

Comment: well I found out how to make it go away... just set width of body to 100%... Its a strange fix but it works... If somebody wants to answer this question...maybe they could explain how setting width to 100% and not 100vw makes it work.

Comment: Maybe there's something wrong with the logo? By the looks of it that seems to be the exact width you're lacking on the right side. Also your navigation is centered compared to the container below. Could try to remove some elements in the console to find the culprit. In my experience it's usually an image (mostly on mobile view tho).

Comment: It was not the logo...infact the logo was totally in a different div...it had something to do with how wide the body element of the html page

Comment: Well, it sounds like a work-around for your problem. Feel free to share some code in a jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting things in **container**, make a div with the classes **row** & **justify-content-center** into the container, then add your content to this div you made.
Hope this helps you

Comment: Container adds a nice all enclosing div... And gives a decent padding to things

Comment: I didn't mean to delete your container : 1. Make container 2. Make a div with classes **row** and **justify-content-center** inside your container 3. Then add other contents